# TestNG ERROR : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file

Tags: testng

Strange error.
**[TestNG] [ERROR] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.**

I tried below

- Made sure the xml has no special/weird  characters.
- tried removing
  "?xml version.." from both file but :). But interestingly when I
  removed the suite-file path (and left "suite-files" tag empty) I got
  the below success message.

  **[TestNG] Running:
    /Users/manny/Documents/workspace/app/testng.xml:

   Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0**
- Double checked my login.xml files, then tried but again same error.
- gave a file name (loginxx.xml) that does not exist, but again same error.

The command I am using to run the files.

> java -classpath /Users/manny/Documents/workspace/MyAppTest/dist/lib/*:
>   org.testng.TestNG -testjar
>   /Users/manny/Documents/workspace/MyAppTest/dist/MyAppTest.jar

My jar file contains testng.xml & login.xml. (note when I execute the xml file directly from Netbeans it works like a champ)

```
**testng.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
 <suite name="MyAppTest">
 <parameter name="selenium.port" value="8081" />
 <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="*firefox" />
 <parameter name="selenium.url" value="http://myapp/api" />

 <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="./login1.xml"></suite-file>
    <suite-file path="./login2.xml" />
 </suite-files>
</suite>
```

**login1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="login">
 <test name="App Login">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.app.test.BaseLoginTest">
            <methods>
                <include name="launch" />
                <include name="invalidPassword" />
                <include name="loginAsAdmin" />
                <include name="logout" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Lastly I tried removing the suites from testng.xml and added the test cases from login.xml to testng.xml it worked.

```
<test name="App Login">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.app.test.BaseLoginTest">
            <methods>
                <include name="launch" />
                <include name="invalidPassword" />
                <include name="loginAsAdmin" />
                <include name="logout" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Why is this not working. any guess ?

```
  <suite-files>
<suite-file path="./login1.xml"></suite-file>
<suite-file path="./login2.xml" />
</suite-files>
```